# How to set custom templateBase as base template

Tags: c#, .net, razorengine

I made custom template using TemplateBase. How to set my template as razor base template. I managed to do this using old api but than I had problem with caching. In new api caching seems much easier but I can't find any example of setting own template as base template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your start up routine or similar, add the following

```
var templateConfig = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
{
    BaseTemplateType = typeof(YourCustomTemplateBase<>)
};

var service = RazorEngineService.Create(templateConfig);

Engine.Razor = service;
```

Add your template base should be created as

```
public abstract class YourCustomTemplateBase<T> : TemplateBase<T>
{
    public string CustomString { get; set; }
}
```